# Laravel How to Make Array into a Collection?

Tags: arrays, laravel

Good day everyone, I have this function that can generate time interval and store them to $time.

```
if(strtotime($startTime) <= strtotime($endTime))
        {
          $this->time[$i]['room'] = '49';
          $this->time[$i]['day'] = 'T-Th';
          $this->time[$i]['c_time'] = $start.'-'.$end;
          $this->time[$i]['sy'] = '2021-2022';
          $this->time[$i]['sem'] = '1st';
        }
```

Sample output of $time is like this

```
1 => array:5 [▼
    "room" => "49"
    "day" => "T-Th"
    "c_time" => "07:00-08:30"
    "sy" => "2021-2022"
    "sem" => "1st"
  ]
  2 => array:5 [▼
    "room" => "49"
    "day" => "T-Th"
    "c_time" => "08:30-10:00"
    "sy" => "2021-2022"
    "sem" => "1st"
  ]
  3 => array:5 [▼
    "room" => "49"
    "day" => "T-Th"
    "c_time" => "10:00-11:30"
    "sy" => "2021-2022"
    "sem" => "1st"
  ]]
```

**What should I do so that the output would be a collection->toArray() just like this**

```
array:5 [▼
  0 => {#1416 ▼
    +"room": "49"
    +"day": "M-W"
    +"c_time": "13:00-14:00"
    +"sy": "2021-2022"
    +"sem": "1st"
  }
  1 => {#1435 ▼
    +"room": "49"
    +"day": "M-W"
    +"c_time": "11:30-13:00"
    +"sy": "2021-2022"
    +"sem": "1st"
  }
  2 => {#1433 ▼
    +"room": "49"
    +"day": "M-W"
    +"c_time": "13:00-14:30"
    +"sy": "2021-2022"
    +"sem": "1st"
  }]
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck? Why not generate a collection in the first place?

Comment: Yeah, How should i do it so that it would generate a collection?

Comment: In the docs you can find everyting about collections . https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#method-push

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you did not provide us with where you define the `$time` variable, I can't help you with any issues there. However, first, instantiate that variable as a collection.

```
$this->time = collect([]);
```

And then you can push in the following manner.

```
 $this->time->put($i, (object) [
    'room' => '49',
    'day' => 'T-Th',
    'c_time' => $start.'-'.$end,
    'sy' => '2021-2022',
    'sem' => '1st',
 ]);
```

Comment: can I ask something?

Comment: You already did :) Go ahead.

Comment: Hahahha, from my question what the difference between the first array(top) and the second array(bottom)?

Comment: @itsmejoe The first is an array of arrays, and the second is an array of objects. You need to push an object instead of an array to achieve that result.

Comment: Okay now I understand, so how should one create an array of objects?

Comment: The thing is I have this function that only accepts array of objects. Keep getting this Attempt to assign property "status" on array

Comment: @itsmejoe I've edited the answer to typecast the array to an object.

Comment: At last, did'nt just the the ($object) would the thing..Big thanks big thanks

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to convert an array to collection is to use Laravel's `collect()` helper function. It takes an array as a parameter and returns a collection type.

For example if we have this array:

```
$a = [
       ['name' => "abc", 'age' =>45],
       ['name' => "xyz", 'age' =>20],
     ];
        dd(collect($a));
```

The output will be:

[image]

Comment: Very good, but i would suggest to build the collection instead of building the array

Comment: Although I appreciate the answer but I am asking how do    i construct the $time to return collection, because what i have done so far returns an array of arrays.